# Using angularjs dropDown directive multiple times in a page, How to close directive when click of another and getting values of that particular

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm very much new to angular. Making a dropDown directive for selecting projects on each and every entries on listings of my website. Well I've just started.

```
app.directive('dropDown', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        template: '<div class="btn-group">\n' +
        '     <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-custom btn-default" ng-click="btnClick()"> Hey'+
        '     </button>' +
        '       <div ng-show="divFlag">' +
        '           Directive Content' +
        '       </div> ' +
        ' </div>'link: function ($scope, elem, attr) {
            $scope.divFlag = false;
            $scope.btnClick = function () {
                $scope.divFlag = !$scope.divFlag;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

with this, when I click on a button, it will show the `<div>` but when clicking on another, first one won't get collapse still second shows. Though my website will contain many like this but I've used just two for now.

```
<drop-down></drop-down>
<drop-down></drop-down>
```

I want them to expand only one at the time. in a click of another, expanded one must be collapsed. Please help me guys. This is quit awkward to me.

Answer (score 0):

They are under new and isolate scope which means each directive works on its own. 
You need to share something between the directives to control when to show and hide.

You need to write a parent directive that controls what is shown and hidden. Child directive doesn't take on the responsbility of hiding/showing its siblings.

1) look into directive inheritance
2) create a parent directive with show/hide functions which are accessed via child
3) on click parent directive sets some property on that child directive to show/hide then calls oppoosite on other directives (that weren't clicked, some kind of a loop to set all hidden and one to show)

I wont write code since you're learning but if you can't figure it out create a plunker and I will update it with working code.

the same can be done without parent directive and by simply using a controller with a function show/hide that loops through child properties and sets show/hide.